# Is it possible to pass an array to content_for (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jammit

Suppose I have a main layout, a nested layout, and a view. Each has its own CSS file associated with it.

Is it possible to pass the two CSS files for the nested layout and the view to the main layout so that it can include all three files into a single call to Jammit's include_stylesheets (via content_for)?

The purpose is to leverage Jammit's concatenation functionality in prod.

I *could* use eval, but I'd like to avoid using that function.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code sample. Personnaly, I can't see Jammit constraints.

Comment: Given I understand correctly, why not include all CSS partials at all times? The beauty of Jammit is, that it creates a single (compressed and gzipped) CSS files out of as many partials as you like (as defined in assets.yml) which then can be cached on the client side. Creating many different files for different sections of your page seems not smart. If you have duplicate selectors and worry about overridden styles, use a body class/id to separate the blocks.